# .htaccess - preventing part/full RewriteRule acting into a subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, security, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, subdirectory

I have a .htaccess on the root of my website, with many RewriteRule conditions for security purpose. One of them, for the example, is the following :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(globals|encode|localhost|loopback).* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(md5|benchmark|cast|request|select|insert|union|declare|drop).* [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
```

I'd like to allow `md5|benchmark` into a subfolder, and allow the whole following in another subfolder :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(globals|encode|localhost|loopback).* [NC,OR]
```

How can I cancel part of such RewriteRule or a whole one ?

Answer (score 0):

In the `/subfolder1/.htaccess` have this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(globals|encode|localhost|loopback).* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(cast|request|select|insert|union|declare|drop).* [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

In the `/subfolder2/.htaccess` have this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(md5|benchmark|cast|request|select|insert|union|declare|drop).* [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```